# Change src in iframe /Javascript

Tags: javascript, select, onchange

I have a problem

I do not know much of Javascript, just the basics.
I have this code.
But when you select an option from the list, DO NOT change the address "src" of the iframe.

Why is that?

This code Javascript

```
lstLinks = new Array(
"//e.issuu.com/embed.html#0/5202806",
"//e.issuu.com/embed.html#0/5203170",
"//e.issuu.com/embed.html#0/5203091",
"//e.issuu.com/embed.html#0/5203144"
); 


function changeTest ()
{ 
var Index = document.menuForm.select1.options[document.menuForm.select1.selectedIndex].value; 

document.testStar.src = lstLinks[Index]; 

}
```

This html

```
<form action="../action/return.html" method="post" id="menuForm" name="menuForm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
      <select id="select1" onchange="changeTest()" name="select1">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Escoger</option>
        <option value="1">Diapositiva 1</option>
        <option value="2">Diapositiva 2</option>
        <option value="3">Diapositiva 3</option>
      </select>
    </form>

       <iframe id="testStar" name="testStar" width="170" height="205" src="//e.issuu.com/embed.html#0/5203197" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This demo: 
    http://jsfiddle.net/VzJNt/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use:

```
document.getElementById("testStar").src = lstLinks[Index];
```

as this is the cross browser way of getting a DOM reference to an item with an id.

You should also check the browser's error console and see what javascript errors are reported on your page when it loads and/or when you change the select.